# PostgreSQL Trigger Copy New Row into other Table

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I have a problem I am stuck on for some time now. So I wanted to reach out for a little help.

I have 2 tables which are holding the same data: transactions and transactions2.

I want to write a Trigger that is triggering every time a new row is added to transactions and insert it into transaction2 in PLSQL.

First I simply duplicated the table with

`CREATE TABLE transactions2 (SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE 1=1);`

I think I found out how to insert

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION copyRow RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$ 
DECLARE 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO transaction2 
VALUES transaction; 
END;`

I think the syntax with this is also wrong, but how do I say, that the Trigger should start as soon as a new Insert into the first table is made?

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks
Bobby

Comment: What have you tried, what are you having problems with?

Comment: First I simply duplicated the table with `CREATE TABLE transactions2 (SELECT * FROM.transactions WHERE 1=1);`

Comment: I think I found out how to insert 
`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION copyRow RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO 
    transaction2
    VALUES
        transaction;
END;`
I think the syntax with this is also wrong, but how do I say, that the Trigger should start as soon as a new Insert into the first table is made?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct syntax for an `INSERT` is `INSERT (<column list>) VALUES (<values list>)`. The `INSERT` syntax isn't different in a function compared to "outside". So your trigger function should look something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION t2t2_f ()
RETURNS TRIGGER
AS
$$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO transactions2
              (column_1,
               ...,
               column_n)
              VALUES (NEW.column_1,
                      ...,
                      NEW.column_n);

  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Replace the `column_i`s with the actual column names of your table. `NEW` is a pseudo record with which you can access the values of the new row.

To create the trigger itself use something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t2t2_t
       AFTER INSERT
       ON transactions
       FOR EACH ROW
       EXECUTE PROCEDURE t2t2_f();
```

You may want to use another timing, e.g. `BEFORE` instead of `AFTER`.

That should give you something to start with. Please consider studying the comprehensive [PostgreSQL Manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/manuals/) for further and more detailed information.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and detailed answer. Just to understand it better I have a question. NEW is referencing to the New Row, created in transactions, because it is specified in the Trigger itself? Do I get it right? Thanks again!

Comment: @BobbyP: Sounds like it, yes.

Comment: In case of adding a column to parent table I would like not to have to update `history` table and `function`. Is there a way to automatically maintain changes in `parent` table?